# iframe shows MIME warning pdfmake: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf:

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, vue.js, pdfmake

We're writing a SPA using Vue.js. We want to generate a PDF clientside and are using pdfMake for that purpose (package available in npm with that name).

According to the documentation, in order to view the PDF inside an `<iframe>`, you can simply add the generated pdf URL to the `src` attribute of the `<iframe>`.

```
const pdfDocGenerator = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
pdfDocGenerator.getDataUrl((dataUrl) => {
    const targetElement = document.querySelector('#iframeContainer');
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = dataUrl;
    targetElement.appendChild(iframe);
});
```

This, however, throws a warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJf////8KOCAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YX ...
```

My html code regarding to the `<iframe>` is:

```
<iframe id="idIframe" type="application/pdf"
          class="col s12" style="height:100%;"
          ></iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
this.pdfObject = pdfMake.createPdf(contentDefinition);
this.pdfObject.getDataUrl((dataUrl) => {
    const iframe = document.querySelector('#idIframe');
    iframe.src = dataUrl;
});
```

This happens in Chrome browser version `63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

If you need more info, just let me know!

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally. Just use an `embed` node instead of `iframe`:

```
<embed height="100%" class="col s12" id="idIframe" src="about:blank" type="application/pdf">
```

Comment: In Chrome actual version you still get the warning, also with object type tag